# How do I slow speed on gaming mouse?

Tags: graphics, mouse, games, blender

I set the "Mouse Speed" in "Settings" as low as it can go on my gaming mouse but it is still too fast. Searching I found many people with the same issue. The solution was to use xinput which I did like:

`xinput set-prop "pointer:Razer Razer Mamba Elite" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.3 0 0 0 0.3 0 0 0 1`

However this is does not work because every graphic program I use like Blender and KiCAD will jump the mouse around when zooming or other actions making it unusuable.

I tried setting all the properties to a minimum:

`xinput --list-props "pointer:Razer Razer Mamba Elite"`

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (470):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (471):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (474):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (475):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (476):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (477): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (478): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (479):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (480):    0
libinput Accel Speed (481): -1.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (482): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (483):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (484):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (485):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (486): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (487): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (267): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):    0, 0
Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event18"
Device Product ID (271):    5426, 108
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (472):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (473):   1
```

This is very frustrating as a linux enthusiast to see such a simple thing be so complicated.

Does anyone know how to slow the mouse down without making  graphical programs unusable?

Comment: Does the mouse have its own driver you can install?

Comment: Change your DPI settings. Your mouse, if [this](https://www.razer.com/gaming-mice/razer-mamba-elite/RZ01-02560100-R3M1) is it, has a very high DPI. So, if you move it an inch it will zoom across the screen. A low DPI will move the cursor less distance per increment of mouse travel. A higher DPI does the opposite. The DPI on that thing is up to 16000.

Answer (score 0):

I found a driver that I was able to change the DPI. https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer

Still would be nice to be able to do from the operating system instead of mouse firmware.